# Do I need a streaming server if I want to connect via SRTP or RTSPS (encrypted) to a IP camera?

Tags: encryption, rtsp, rtp

I want to secure the image data that I get from my IP camera in order to protect from somebody sniffing on the network.
At the moment I am using RTSP to access my camera from my client without any server in between.
When I was reading about secure ways of transmitting the data I found RTSPS and SRTP.
AXIS gives some information about SRTP with their cameras and they show a video management server (VMS). 
Here you can find it on page 11:
https://www.axis.com/files/brochure/ebook_genetec_axis_network_encryption_en_1808_lo.pdf

So, my question would be if I need a streaming server or a video management server if I want to connect via SRTP or RTSPS to an IP camera or can I directly connect from a client?

Thanks

J.